# publishing asp.net website for testing on local IIS server

Tags: asp.net, authentication, compiler-errors, publish, visual-studio-express

I am redesigning my company's website.  **I am not a developer,** but have learned as I went along.  I am ready to push out my site to a test subdomain, but I can't figure out how to publish it correctly using VS Express for Web 2013.  I have multiple problems.

First, we have our own internal IIS server and I have a "site3" folder on the server ready for testing the new site.  I can't use Web Deploy or Web Deploy Package.  I publish using File System.  This seems to sorta work, but no images load and it redirects me to a Login page that I have no intention of using.  **When I run the site on my local machine, everything works 100% fine** - no login page and all site resources load and function perfectly.

Second, when I try to publish, there is no "Release" configuration like I see in online tutorials and MSDN, only "Debug."  Is there something I'm missing in the configuration? The publishing?  Am I using the wrong framework?  This is my first rodeo and I am completely lost.

If anyone wants to look at my completely jacked up site, it's http://site3.tcns.net

EDIT: I'm beginning to think that it has something to do with the fact I have no clue how to configure the web.config file and the default file isn't plug-and-play for a basic website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some idea as to what happened.  I accidentally created an MVC solution instead of a basic website.